# Can I change the Drupal password policy without using an external module?

Tags: drupal, passwords, policy

I would like to change the password policy for a Drupal v6.x site. Specifically, I'd like to remove the 1 number + 1 capital + 1 character constraint. Is there any way to do this, *without installing an new module*?

Comment: For those whom it might help: If I need to break down and use a module, http://drupal.org/project/password_policy looks applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only requirement is that the passwords match. You can remove the password warnings by adding

```
.password-description{display:none !important;}
```

to your css.